# unable to install tensorflow: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

### Im using anaconda, I created an enviroment called proyecto, then after activating it I wrote "conda install tensorflow" and this was the result:

(proyecto) C:\Users\min2>conda install tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- tensorflow

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-32
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

### and use the search bar at the top of the page.

I have no idea whats going on because I use to have tensorflow on this PC. I've seen similar problems but none of them helped me.

Comment: You could try using pip: "pip install tensorflow" or install it in the UI of Anaconda Navigator, create a new environment.

Comment: I already fixed it, the problem was that I was using anaconda x86, I reinstalled it as x64 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @drop90prog, After installing x64 version it works why because
Tensorflow is tested and supported on the 64-bit Windows system.

Refer the [Tensorflow portal](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) for more information.